# Android - How to check scroll position in expandable height GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-scrollview, onmeasure

I use `expandable height GridView` in my Fragment. It's default GridView with overridden `onMeasure` method. This allows to use this `GridView` inside `ScrollView` which wrap the fragment with this GridView.

```
boolean expanded = false;    
public boolean isExpanded() {
    return expanded;
}
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (isExpanded()) {
        // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
        // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

But I have a problem to checking what items of `GridView` is displaying on the screen. All methods that can help me don't work with overridden `onMeasure` because all items displayed at one time when `GridView` creating.

getScrollY() - always returns 0, because GridView already expanded by overridden onMeasure and doesn't scroll.

`onScrollListener's` parameters are just a range of visible child-views from 0 to last item because all of them are displayed (by onMeasure), not the actual scroll-position.